# Show that there is a point $x_0\in\Bbb{R}^n$ such that $Df(x_0)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, scalar-fields

> Let $f : \Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}$ be a $C^1$ function such that  $$\lim\limits_{\|x\|\to\infty}f(x)=0$$ Show that there is a point $x_0 \in \Bbb{R}^n$ such that $Df(x_0)=0$.

---

I'm struggling to finish the proof. My idea was to distinguish some case. Let for example suppose that there is $z\in \Bbb{R}^n$ such that $f(z)>0$. Let $\epsilon>0$. By limit hypothesis at infinity we have the existence of $c>0$ s.t $\|x\|\ge c \implies |f(x)|<f(z)$. The idea now is to look what's going on in the set $\overline{B(0,c)}$. As $f$ is continuous and $\overline{B(0,c)}$ is a compact set, then $f$ has it's max and min there. But, I'm struggling to show that max cannot occur on the board of my close ball. If someone could help I would appreciate it. Thank you

Comment: The max cannot occur on the boundary $\{x : \|x\|=c\}$ because of your choice of $c$.

Comment: What is $ D f $?

Comment: Jacobean of $f$

Comment: @Daniil Do scalar fields have Jacobians?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As GEdgar commented, the maximum can't be attained in the boundary due to construction: the maximum of $f$ is not less than $f(z)$, but on the boundary of the $c$-ball the values of $f$ are strictly less than $f(z)$.

---

As a remark, in a slightly different way one can argue as follows also:

We may assume that $f$ is not constantly zero. Via the inverse of stereographic projection (which is a diffeomorphism), adding a new point and extending $f$ to be $0$ at the added new point $\infty$ we have a continuous function $F$ on the sphere $S^n$ that coincides with $f\circ\sigma$ everywhere except the added point, where $\sigma$ is the stereographic projection. $F$ attains its maximum and minimum, say at $p$ and $q$, respectively. They can't both be equal to $\infty$ for then $f=0$, so at least one of them is in the domain of $\sigma$, say $p$. Then $F(p)=f\circ\sigma(p)$, and $F'(p)=0$.

Comment: Alright thank you! And for the case when $f(z)<0$ I can just take its absolute value and argue on min ?